# test command in unix doesn't print output

Tags: bash, command

Why is there no output to the command `test 3 -lt 6` in the unix terminal? Shouldn't test output a 0 or a 1?

I did a man test and it says

> Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION

Comment: One of the many many things `test` does not do. Perhaps you are looking for `echo`?

Answer (score 4):

The exit status is not printed, it is just returned. You can test it in `if` or `while`, for example

```
if test 3 -lt 6 ; then
    echo ok
else
    echo not ok
fi
```

Moreover, the exit code of the last expression is kept in `$?`:

```
test 3 -lt 6; echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

`test` returns an exit status, which is the one that indicates if the test was succesfull. You can get it by reading `$?` right after executing `test` or you can use it directly in a control structure, for example:

```
if test 3 -lt 6 
  do echo "everything is aaaaalright"
  else echo "whaaat?"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

*Every* command in the shell has a return value, not just `test`.  Return values are rairly printed, we test them directly, for example with an `if` or `while` statement, or maybe use it in a shortcut with `&&` or `||`.  Sometimes we might store the return value, which is also available in the variable `?`.

The `test` command is rather ancient.  Since you have tagged `bash` then you might wish to consider using

```
if (( 3 < 6 )); then
```

for arithmetic tests, or

```
if [[ $name == "Fred Bloggs" ]] ; then
```

for textual or pattern tests.

These are generally more intuitive and less error prone. Like `test`, `((   ))` and `[[ ]]` are commands in their own right, and can be used without `if` or `while`.  They return 0 (success) on true, and 1 (failure) on false.

By the way, when you do a `man test` you are actually looking at the doc for the `test` program.  You might be better using `man bash` or `help test`.